# Assign two different classes/ID's to attribute:hover

Tags: css

I'm working on a tumblr theme where the individual posts display the link to permalink page on hover and the post beneath it blurs. 
`.entry:hover #permalink` and `.entry:hover img {-webkitfilter:blur}` work both individually, but not together. Maybe I'm doing the CSS wrong when I try to assign `.entry:hover` to two different attributes. Or is it a problem of `z-index` and `position`?

Can I use jQuery to make something like "if entry hover shows permalink -> blur entry img" ?

[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NUBkp/146/)

css:

```
body{
position:absolute;
}
.entry {
float:left;
width:100%;
}
.entry #permalink {
position:absolute;
width:100%;
opacity:0.0;

}
.entry:hover #permalink {
    opacity: 1;
    text-align:center;
    }
.entry img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(0px);
}
.entry:hover img {
    -webkit-filter: blur(5px);
}
```

html:

```
<div class="entry">
<div id="permalink"><a href="#">post number x</a></div>
<img src="#" alt="#" width="500px"/>
</div>
```

Comment: jquery will be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just add `z-index:100;` or something else bigger to your `.entry:hover #permalink`, here is [working demo](https://jsfiddle.net/NUBkp/149/)